# Why does an IF condition in a batch file interpret 3 being greater than 2*2?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to make a infinite leveling system for a little personal game I'm making, but it doesn't work. This is what it looks like.

```
if %exp% gtr %lvl%*%lvl% goto lvlup
:lvlup
set /a exp=%exp%-%lvl%*%lvl%
set /a cmhealth=%cmhealth%+5
set /a cchealth=%cchealth%+5
set /a cattack=%cattack%+3
set /a cDefence=%cDefence%+4
set /a cspeed=%cspeed%+2
set /a lvl=%lvl%+1
set /a SP=%SP%+1
goto decisions
```

It runs fine until it gets to something like:

```
if 3 GTR 2*2 goto lvlup
set /a exp=3-2*2
set /a cmhealth=25+5
set /a cchealth=18+5
set /a cattack=8+3
set /a cDefence=15+4
set /a cspeed=8+2
set /a lvl=2+1
set /a SP=1+1
goto decisions
```

And `exp` is then set to `-1`.

Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

The problem is it doesn't read 2*2 as 4 or 3*3 as 9.

Comment: You can't do arithmetics in `if` statements, you can only compare single values, so you have to calculate `%lvl%*%lvl%` in advance by a `set /A` statement and use its result for the comparison; if you have `2*2` in an `if` statement, it is compared as a string...

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **IF** command compares primary strings.

**IF** compares also integer numbers if both strings can be converted successfully internally to 32-bit signed integer numbers and command extensions are enabled as by default and using as comparison operator `EQU`, or `NEQ`, or `LSS`, or `LEQ`, or `GTR`, or `GEQ`.

But **IF** does not evaluate expressions like command **SET** with parameter `/A`.

Run in a command prompt window `if /?` for help on this command.

As the string `2*2` can't be converted to an integer because of `*` in string, the command **IF** runs a string comparison to evaluate if left string is greater than right string.

A string comparison is done by comparing the bytes of the two strings byte by byte until either end of one of the two strings is reached or the currently compared bytes of the two strings are not equal.

The decimal values of the bytes for the two strings are:

- `3` ... 51
- `2*2` ... 50 42 50

51 is greater than 50 and therefore the string `3` is greater than the string `2*2` and batch execution continues with jump to label `lvlup`.

So it is necessary to first evaluate the expression `%lvl%*%lvl%` with `set /A` and assign the result to an environment variable for comparing the result next with another environment variable holding also an integer number.

```
set /A result=lvl * lvl
if %exp% GTR %result% goto lvlup

:lvlup
set /A exp-=result
set /A cmhealth+=5
set /A cchealth+=5
set /A cattack+=3
set /A cDefence+=4
set /A cspeed+=2
set /A lvl+=1
set /A SP+=1
goto decisions
```

As help of command **SET** output by running in a command prompt window `set /?` explains, variable names in expression after `set /A` usually must not and should not be referenced with using `%VariableName%` (immediate expansion) or `!VariableName!` (delayed expansion). Space separated strings which are definitely not integer numbers or operators in arithmetic expression are automatically interpreted as variable names which current string value should be converted internally to a 32-bit signed integer for evaluating the arithmetic expression.